# Ubuntu cant turn on dev/sda2 and also diamonds

Tags: development

When I boot the computer it says:

```
/dev/sda2 contains file system with errors
```

And when I try to type, I see white diamonds instead of characters:

[image: IMAGE OF THE PROBLEM]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have your Ubuntu installation USB nearby? That would most likely be the easiest way to repair the disk; boot into a Live Session and perform the file system checks from there 

Comment: Thanks i will check it